# BeautifulSoup, findAll after findAll?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm pretty new to Python and mainly need it for getting information from websites.
Here I tried to get the short headlines from the bottom of the website, but cant quite get them.

```
from bfs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://some-website"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

nachrichten = soup.findAll('ul', {'class':'list'})
```

Now I would need another findAll to get all the links/a from the var "nachrichten", but how can I do this ?

Comment: I dont think there is bfs4. I never herd of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a *css selector* with select if you want all the links in a single list:

```
anchors = soup.select('ul.list a')
```

If you want individual lists:

```
anchors = [ ul.find_all(a) for a in soup.find_all('ul', {'class':'list'})]
```

Also if you want the hrefs you can make sure you only find the anchors with *href* attributes and extract:

```
hrefs = [a["href"] for a in soup.select('ul.list a[href]')]
```

With  `find_all` set *href=True* i.e `ul.find_all(a, href=True)` .

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "http://www.n-tv.de/ticker/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
nachrichten = soup.findAll('ul', {'class':'list'})
links = []
for ul in nachrichten:
    links.extend(ul.findAll('a'))
print len(links)
```

Hope this solves your problem and I think the import is bs4. I never herd of bfs4